# Seeking Open Source implementation of Majority Filter?

Tags: geotiff-tiff, software-recommendations, filter, opencv

I am performing postprocessing on Landsat GeoTIFF images and want to use the Majority Filter as mentioned in the book on [Image Analysis, Classification and Change Detection in Remote Sensing](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=fGDOBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA285&dq=majority%20filter%20image%20processing%20remote%20sensing&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwixtsaJzNXZAhUKv48KHewWChwQ6AEITzAH#v=onepage&q=majority%20filter%20image%20processing%20remote%20sensing&f=false) and [ArcGIS Pro documentation](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/majority-filter.htm).

Is there a Majority filter implementation available which is open source?

Perhaps someone can suggest a filter in OpenCV which gives results similar to Majority Filtering.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The open-source geospatial analysis library ***WhiteboxTools*** has a majority filter that works for single-band GeoTIFF images. You can download the library's compiled binaries from [here](http://www.uoguelph.ca/%7Ehydrogeo/software.shtml#WhiteboxTools), the project code repository is [here](https://github.com/jblindsay/whitebox-tools), and source code for the majority filter tool is [here](https://github.com/jblindsay/whitebox-tools/blob/master/src/tools/image_analysis/majority_filter.rs). Instructions for how to call functions using Python can be found in the [user manual](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/323547863_WhiteboxTools_User_Manual). Here is an example of a Python script calling the majority filter tool:

```py
from whitebox_tools import WhiteboxTools

wbt = WhiteboxTools()
wbt.work_dir = "/path/to/data/"
wbt.majority_filter("image.tif", "filtered.tif", filterx=15, filtery=15)
```

The following is an example of applying a 15 x 15 majority filter to a portion of a Landsat image, band 1:

[image: Band1 unfiltered]

[image: Band1 filtered]

I should also add the disclaimer that I am the developer of the WhiteboxTools library.

Comment: Installation links: https://github.com/jblindsay/whitebox-geospatial-analysis-tools/tree/master/whitebox_tools#2-downloads-and-installation, https://github.com/conda-forge/whitebox_tools-feedstock